# Running ubuntu based container image on Centos is slower than on Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, centos7

I have a question about Centos 7 vs Ubuntu 16.04 with docker
Let assume that we have a container image that is based on Ubuntu 16.04 with a lot of systemcall
Running the container image  above

1. on the machine whose host os is Centos 7.9
2. on the machine whose host os is Ubuntu 16.04

Which one is faster? if then is that meaningful?

Answer (score 1):

Linux Docker images communicate directly with the Linux kernel.

If you have the same kernel version and the same docker version on the host machine, the docker image will run exactly the same.

Whether you have CentOS or Ubuntu running on the host, they can both have the same Linux kernel, and then it won't make a difference.

Comment: Thank you so much
I've never though about the kernel.
The continainer is using WINE to run window exe file on container.
So, I should check the compatiability between WINE and kernel 3.10.0